# google.com requesting password?! Is my router / firefox / computer infected?

Tags: firefox, password, google, malware

When I type "google.com" or "http://google.com" into the address bar in Firefox I end up with the following screen requesting some login and password.

[image: Firefox requesting password at google.com]

When I try the same in Chrome or Opera, I get redirected to www.google.com or www.google.pl. I killed dnsmasq and in /etc/hosts there's nothing similar to google.com.

When I press Cancel, I get the following error 401 message.

[image: error 401]

What is going on? Is it a virus? But why is it active only for Firefox?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

I use an up-to-date Ubuntu 12.04 with Firefox 26.0.

**Update:** I first noticed the problem, when I lost my internet connection (I mean formally there was a connection, but there was no or hardly any transfer) without any reason (the first thing I did was typing google to check if it is a problem with a single domain or the whole connection).

I just tried the same on another machine with similar configuration (my current Ubuntu was cloned from that a few months ago) and everything is OK...

Comment: That's odd. This is a stab in the dark, but in Firefox, can you go to **Edit** > **Preferences** > **Advanced** > **Network**, and click **Settings...** under _Connection_? Are there any proxy settings there?

Comment: @Alaa Perfect guess! It was 'Use system proxy settings' and after switching to 'No proxy' it is fine - I mean, I get redirected to www.google.pl. But it doesn't explain the root cause of the problem. Do you think there is something wrong about my router?

Comment: No, it's not your router. We have to look at what does "Use system proxy settings" do in Firefox. I don't normally use Firefox, but I think that option tells Firefox to use whatever proxy the operating system is using (i.e what you have configured in the Proxy settings in Ubuntu). But all of this is odd because that means that you have your router configured as the proxy...but why are Chrome and Opera working =)? **Are** you using a proxy anyways? Search and open "Network" in the Ubuntu Dash, and check the Network proxy settings. Are they set to anything?

Comment: I've added my first comment as an answer to your question.

Comment: @Alaa I don't think I use proxy in Ubuntu. In **System Settings** > **Network** > **Network proxy** the chosen *Method* is *None*. Btw. Chrome says '*Google Chrome is using your computer's system proxy settings to connect to the network*' and it is not configurable. And Firefox after choosing 'No proxy' instead of 'Use system proxy settings' works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check the proxy settings on Firefox.

To do so in Firefox, go to **Edit** → **Preferences** → **Advanced** → **Network**, and click **Settings...** under *Connection*. If you aren't using a proxy, set it to *No proxy*, or enter in your correct proxy settings if you're using one.